# Does an Apostle of Peace violate their vows by casting End to Strife?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, class-feature, prestige-class

[*End to Strife*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20031004c) is a spell on the [**Apostle of Peace**](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20031004b) PrC spell list that deals damage to creatures who make attacks in its area, yet an Apostle of Peace is forbidden by their vows from dealing damage.

Does the fact that the target has to consciously make the decision to attack shift the responsibility for their damage from the Apostle of Peace to themselves?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apostle of Peace (or anyone else with the same Vow feats) is forbidden from dealing real damage to living creatures, and there is no exception for conditional spells.

However this isn't a dysfunction, because *End to Strife* has a nonlethal mode, and both Vow of Peace and Vow of Nonviolence allow nonlethal damage.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that!

Comment: By 'isn't a dysfunction' you mean 'is no more dysfunctional than taking Vow of Peace/Nonviolence in the first place', right?

Comment: Shun the non-believer!

Comment: I would add that as the OP asked, the burden of responsibility lies with the creature making the attack, not the apostle. The apostle is no more responsible for somebody taking damage by willfully engaging in attacks within the protected area than they are responsible for a person throwing themselves under the hooves of their horse.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli That sounds it could be the start of a fine standalone answer.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli: This sounds like a slippery slope to me. Setting up a mouse-trap, you do not exercise any violence, and certainly the mouse is free to choose whether go attempt to get the cheese or not. Yet, the end result is often a dead mouse. If injury or death is the likely outcome, and you know it, are you really not inflicting them?

Comment: @MatthieuM.  Would an apostle of peace break their vow if their opponent commits seppuku as a result of losing?

Comment: @MatthieuM. - Kind of. If you build a trap specifically designed to inflict harm, then yes. End of Strife is not that trap. The fact that End of Strife is an Apostle of Peace spell specifically informs it's intent that it is usable by an Apostle of Peace without breaching vows. Further to this is that it has an optional damage output of lethal or non-lethal, the non-lethal clearly being the choice for AoP.